# Python executable crashes built with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I've got a simple script for message encryption and converting result into QR Code. It uses *pycrypto*, *reportlab* and *tkinter*. Here's the source: [click](http://bpaste.net/show/eq335p3DWnNpEkbECYnF/)

It works correctly, but if I build it with cx_Freeze, it crashes when attempting to encrypt a message: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqdE4.jpg)

P.S. I also tried py2exe, but the program crashes on start with no debug output.

Comment: I think this is a bug in cx_Freeze with Python 3.3, caused by a change in the `re` module. Frozen applications can end up with the Python parts of `re` from one Python release, and the compiled parts from a different release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by editing parser.py (C:\Python33\lib\html\parser.py): [patch](http://bpaste.net/show/Bn3MpIGpmcfD5P5q1RCY/)